# SELECT WHERE LIKE returns incomplete results and the reason is not diacritics

Tags: sql, diacritics, collate, hidden-characters

I am searching for results `WHERE name LIKE '%Soucek%'` (or I tried `'%Souček%'` or `'%Soućek%'`. I get one result. (I set the whole column to be `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CI_AS`).
If I search for `'%Sou_ek%'` i get all results there are.
I dont understand what is going on. Do you have an idea?

Comment: In which environment is the query executed? It may be that the environment distorts the accent and sends the wrong query. Can you show results for both queries?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `AI` : "Accent Insensitive" instead of `AS` : "Accent Sensitive".

Also, make sure that both sides have the same [collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms144250(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to avoid errors or further coercions :

```
WHERE name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI Like '%Soucek%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```